# Difference B/W Session and Cookie in Sailjs

Tags: session, cookies, express, sails.js

I've a large application working on and I am facing with hte problem of sessions a lot, it just unset or corrupt the session of my application sometime, all I got it undefined in my session.

By the way I need to know is there any alternative of sessions so I came to know after R&D that I may use cookie, but I think these things are same before .

So I am stuck, don't know how to get rid of my problem.

Now I've some questions as I am a beginner

- what is the difference b/w sessions and cookie in sailsjs.
- how to set and get cookie in sailsjs.

**i am using sails version v0.94**

Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session is a schemaless object that can be saved in memory or a persistent store such as Mongo or Redis. Using a memory store like Redis or Mongo helps to persist your sessions across multiple application servers or during an application restart.

The cookie tracks a user with a specific ID to associate with the session. Sailsjs, on top of Express, manages cookies and sessions automatically. When a user accesses your site it is assigned this cookie that has a unique ID. Then sails/express automatically will associate session information to that particular client based on their unique cookie. Sails does more than express by allowing you to use this with with sockets as well.

This is all done so you don't have to save and update session the same as a normal DB. You just set the property and move on.

The reason not use cookies is if you prefer to keep the information on the client and do not want to create overhead for your server to look for that value in memory or in a DB. You will want to make sure this information does not need to be secure.

To learn how to use cookies you should google "Expressjs Cookies" (remember sails runs on top of express, current version 3.x)

If you want an alternative to sessions / cookies you can look at web tokens http://jwt.io/

Remember sailsjs runs on expressjs if you can't find what your looking for, then always search for an express solution as well.